# How can I find all stored procedures that are using a column in PL SQL?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, toad

I need a Query to find all the stored procedures in my PLSQL DB that are using the column "ID_SUB".

Just in case, are there any Toad options to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find name of the stored procedure using Column name in Oracle 11g](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432948/how-to-find-name-of-the-stored-procedure-using-column-name-in-oracle-11g)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query:

```
 select name, 
        line, 
        text 
   from ALL_SOURCE 
  where text like '%ID_SUB%'
```

Comment: Works!! Thank you!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

All the procedure code will be in the sys.all_source table if you have permission to select from it.  This should get you a little closer:

```
select distinct owner, name
from sys.all_source
where type = 'PROCEDURE'
and text like '%ID_SUB%';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no guaranteed way, but you can search user/all/dba_source using `regexp_like` to check for whole words, and cross-reference that with user/all/dba_dependencies to narrow down the list of packages to check.

```
select s.name, s.type, s.line, s.text
from   user_source s
where  ltrim(s.text,chr(9)||' ') not like '--%'
and    regexp_like(lower(s.text),'\Wyour_column_name_here\W')
and    (s.name, s.type) in
       ( select d.name, d.type
         from   user_dependencies d
         where  d.referenced_owner = user
         and    d.referenced_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE' );
```

or if there could be references to it from other schemas,

```
select s.owner, s.name, s.type, s.line, s.text
from   all_source s
where  ltrim(s.text,chr(9)||' ') not like '--%'
and    regexp_like(lower(s.text),'\Wyour_column_name_here\W')
and    (s.owner, s.name, s.type) in
       ( select d.owner, d.name, d.type
         from   all_dependencies d
         where  d.referenced_owner = user
         and    d.referenced_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE' );
```

You might make it just use `select distinct s.owner, s.name, s.type ...` to get a list of objects to investigate.

(Repeating my answer to [How to find name of the stored procedure using Column name in Oracle 11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432948/how-to-find-name-of-the-stored-procedure-using-column-name-in-oracle-11g?noredirect=1&lq=1) which I realised after posting was 5 years old. Hope that's OK with SO etiquette.)